# Crypto key not available in android offline implementation of exoplayer

Tags: android, key, offline, exoplayer

so i have this error while working with offline implementation of exoplayer am using 2.11.5 and tried 2.15.1

right now the error output is this

```
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal: Playback error
      com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlaybackException: MediaCodecVideoRenderer error, index=0, format=Format(1, null, null, video/avc, avc1.4D4028, -1, null, [1440, 1080, -1.0], [-1, -1]), format_supported=YES
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.handleMessage(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:558)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
     Caused by: android.media.MediaCodec$CryptoException: Crypto key not available: 1 (Unknown error -1)
      ============================== Beginning of DRM Plugin Log ==============================
        10-02 15:01:28.206 I found instance=clearkey version=android.hardware.drm@1.4::IDrmFactory
        10-02 15:01:28.207 I found instance=default version=android.hardware.drm@1.0::IDrmFactory
        10-02 15:01:28.207 I found instance=widevine version=android.hardware.drm@1.4::IDrmFactory
        10-02 15:01:29.425 E Not implemented
      ============================== End of DRM Plugin Log ==============================
        at android.media.MediaCodec.native_queueSecureInputBuffer(Native Method)
        at android.media.MediaCodec.queueSecureInputBuffer(MediaCodec.java:2904)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.SynchronousMediaCodecAdapter.queueSecureInputBuffer(SynchronousMediaCodecAdapter.java:148)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.feedInputBuffer(MediaCodecRenderer.java:1367)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.render(MediaCodecRenderer.java:825)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.doSomeWork(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:978)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.handleMessage(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:482)
              ... 4 more
```

i gave the key in base64 and also checked if there where any + or / chars and replaced with - and _